# MYSQL Query for taking out all of the users that are didnt attend today

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey i am working with a project and i am looking for some assistance again ..
So i have 2 table one contain info about employee and and other on is table if he attend so basically it takes the employee id and put it in that table and mark his attendance . I hope i am clear till here . 
What i am trying to achieve is a query that will gives me all the people that didn't attend today .
here is a structure for both table[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EskpL.png) 
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgTjh.png)
In second table a person will mark his attendence through his cell phone and if he didnt there will be

> no entry in the second table .

so here comes the tricky part that need to be solved 
LOOK AT THIS TOO [Front End Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6SBG.png)

Comment: post the query you have tried.

Comment: function didntattend(){
    $con = db();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `employes` WHERE `stats` = 1 ";
    $exe= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($exe){
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe)){
            $id = $row['em_id'];
            $query = STUCK HERE MIND NOT WORKING 
            
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from employees where !(employees.id = todaytable.trackingID)
```

this should do